# Accessing X64 Static library in webservice through Wrapper dll

Tags: c#, c++, web-services, winapi, static-libraries

I have a static library X64 bit. I created a wrapper and executed through console application it works fine.When i use the same wrapper dll and tried to expose the methods through webservice getting the error.

Code snippet:
**Wrapper**

```
#include "Header.h"
#include "sonobox.hpp"
namespace MyWin32DLL
{
    MyWin32ClassOne::MyWin32ClassOne()
    {
        varone = 123;
    }

   __declspec(dllexport) int MyWin32ClassOne::getoutput()
        {
                    uikey=GetKey();
        }

        return uikey;
    }

}
```

**WEbservice:-**

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [DllImport("Win32Project2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int getoutput();

        [WebMethod]
        public int HelloWorld()
        {          
           return getoutput();

        }
    }
```

**Error:-**
Could not load file or assembly '***' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Please hep!

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this error is bitness mismatch. The process is 32 bit, the failing assembly 64 bit. Or vice versa. If that is so then you have two possible solutions:

1. Build a 32 bit version of the assembly using a 32 bit version of the static library.
2. Ensure that the web service executes in a 64 bit process.